# Anyone have any information how to breed the new Lunar Eclipse Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I noticed the Lunar Eclipse dragon is in the Dragonvale marketplace, but there is no information on how to breed it, it's also not in the usual places (yet?).  Does anyone know how to breed it?

Answer (score 1):

Hot off the press, you need to breed dragons with the elements Air, Cold and Earth to get the Lunar Eclipse Dragon.

Some examples:

Cold + Sandstorm Dragons  or

Snow + Earth Dragons etc.

Breeding time is 48 hours or 38:24 if you upgraded the island/cave.  Good luck!

Source for information:

[Lunar Eclipse Dragon on Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/lunar-eclipse-dragon/tips-hints)

Answer (score 0):

Mountain + Air is the most popular combination with a 28% chance of a Lunar Eclipse Dragon.

Comment: What is the source of this information?

Answer (score 0):

Any breeding combination that has the air, dark, and earth types. From what I know, you can only breed the lunar eclipse dragon when a lunar eclipse has happened recently. You can also get it from a mystery egg.